# mod_rewrite not working when page exists with same name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page shirts.php which lists all the shirts, and then I have a page product.php?id=X, which displays the individual product information.

If I write the rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^mens_shirts/([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and the input url is `mens_shirts/22` it displays the product page correctly with the clean URL.

However, if I write the rule like follows:

```
RewriteRule ^shirts/([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and the input url is `/shirts/20`, instead of displaying the product page, it displays shirts.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^shirts/([0-9]+)$ product.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

[I believe that happens because you have `MultiViews` enabled, by disabling it, it should let you do what you want. Why, read here.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews)

`FollowSymLinks` - The server will follow symbolic links in this directory.

Comment: Great! Just for my own education, what exactly are +FollowSymLinks and -MultiViews doing?

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me